# Vectors in Each Mahout Cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout

I'm an Apache Mahout newbie. I'm trying to understand which of my named vectors belong to which cluster. A lot of resources on the internet are about text documents and use the commands clusterdump. However, my dataset is really huge and running the command always causes a Java Out Of Memory Exception. Besides, I don't think that using clusterdump would answer my question.

I would like to know if it's possible to understand nothing more than which named vectors belong to which clusters using the directories `clusteredPoints` and `clusters-[0-9]+` and `clusters-*-final`

If it helps, so far, I have formed clusters of users based on their song listening habits. To do this, I initially created a sequence file using NamedVectors where the name of the NamedVector is the userId and the Vector itself is a double array containing weights of the tags of the songs listened by the user (an example is below).

```
    AR2TSU61187FB5C4F0 0.5 0.2 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I then ran k-means successfully. I have the output in the directory clusteredPoints (some 88 files with names such as part-m-00088) and the directory clusters that I believe contain the centroids.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to do some research in clusterdump,try mahout clusterdump --help
try this

```
mahout clusterdump -i clusters-*-final/part-r-00000 -o output -p clusteredPoints/part-m-00000
```

and try this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/cluster-dumper.html) for further explanation.

you can also try to add the option -of CSV,
you will have a display like this :

- id_cluster1,vec1,vec2..vecl
- id_cluster2,vec1,vec2..vecl
- ...